# Halmos Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces: Does $\mathcal{P}$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with $x(t) = x(1 - t)$ form a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Paul R. Halmos "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces", 2e, chapter I, section 2, exercise 5.d:

> Consider the vector space $\mathcal{P}$ and the subsets $\mathcal{V}$
>   of $\mathcal{P}$ consisting of those vectors (polynomials) $x$ for
>   which
>
> (d) $x(t) = x(1 - t)$ for all $t$.
>
> In which of these cases is $\mathcal{V}$ a vector space?

I would suggest that the subset satisfying (d) does form a vector space, since

- (d) forms a linear constraint in the polynomial's coefficients $\mathbf{a}$ as in

$$
g(\mathbf{a}) = x(t) - x(1 - t) = 0,
$$

- the zero vector is included,
- every element has an inverse element.

$g$ is a linear constraint, since 
$$
g(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b}) = g(\mathbf{a}) + g(\mathbf{b}) \qquad \wedge \qquad \alpha g(\mathbf{a}) = g(\alpha \mathbf{a}),
$$
where $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ are coefficients of polynomials in $\mathcal{P}$, and $\alpha$ is a complex number.

Is that correct?

Comment: Is a geometric interpretation of this set of polynomials: all polynomials symmetric relatively to the point 0.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would suggest that the subset satisfying (d) does form a vector space, since
>
> - (d) forms a linear constraint in the polynomial's coefficients,
> - the zero vector is included,
> - every element has an inverse element.
>
> Is that correct?

This is the right idea, but when you say that (d) forms a linear constraint in the coefficients, what do you mean?

I suppose what you mean is that if the polynomial is $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots ...$ then it is some linear equation in $a_0, a_1, \ldots$. But why does this imply that (d) is a vector space?

However you can formalize (d). I would approach this by defining a map
$$
A : \mathcal{P} \to \mathcal{P}
$$

where $A(\boldsymbol{x}) = \boldsymbol{x}(t) - \boldsymbol{x}(1-t)$.

Then, show that $A$ is a linear map -- that is, it preserves addition and scalar multiplication.

Finally, $\mathcal{V}$ is the set of polynomials $\boldsymbol{x}$ such that $A(\boldsymbol{x}) = \boldsymbol{0}$. Since $A$ is linear this is a vector subspace. So this completes your proof.

Answer (score 0):

Your first bullet point is not useful. Just verify the definition. Surely 0 is in there. Every element has an additive inverse. If $c$ is a constant, then $cx(t)=cx(1-t)$, so constant multiples of polynomials are also in there. So you're done.

Comment: What if I doubt that every element has an additive inverse?

Comment: It seems you are  misunderstanding the idea of a proof. You need to *show* this is the case. The constant case is clearly shows the inverse. Just take $c=-1$. However, I did leave out that two functions may not add to satisfy $d$, but this is clear since you just add the contraint equation; i.e. $x(t)+y(t)=x(1-t)+y(1-t)$. You should note that notationally, you should write $(x+y)(t)$ for the aforementioned equation. As well as $(x+y)(1-t)$. This is, by definition, the addition of two polynomials.

Comment: What does $-1 \cdot x(t) = -1 \cdot x(1-t)$ tell me?

Comment: That inverse exist. -x(t) also satisfies (d). It is clearly an additive inverse to x(t).

Comment: I find it impressive that it is obvious to you. I need some more hints and smaller steps in argumentation, I'm afraid. E.g. proof by contradiction: Assume there is an element $x'$ in the subset which does not have an additive inverse. Then $g(-\mathbf{a}') = -x'(t) + x'(1-t) \neq 0$. But $g$ is homogeneous in $\mathbf{a}$. Hence, every element has an additive inverse.

Comment: But I proved to you it exists. If $x(t)$ belongs in $\mathcal{V}$, then $x(t)=x(1-t)$. Multiplying by $-1$ shows $-x(t)$ also belongs in $\mathcal{V}$. Since $x(t)-x(t)=0$, so $-x(t)$ is an additive inverse of $x(t)$. Proof by contradiction is not at all useful in this case; even in some theories such as constructivists theories, you cannot use contradiction since it uses the rule of middle exclusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87902/discussion-between-max-herrmann-and-user495490).